# Reading URLs Asynchronously in Google App Engine

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, sockets, concurrency

Let's say I have the following code in Google App Engine:

```
from urllib import urlopen
...
data1 = urlopen(url2).read()
data2 = urlopen(url2).read()
...
```

To improve the latency, I would like to run these two requests to external URLs asynchronously. How can I do that? I know how to do it in normal Python using a thread pool, but Google App Engine does not seem to support multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the docs? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that document. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ndb tasklets.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#urlfetch

Comment: That's one way to do it, but not the only way - see Rick's response.